# Distribution function technique - check my approach?

Tags: probability-distributions

so I'm learning a new topic and am a bit new to probability, so please excuse my elementary question.

Given a random sample on an exponential distribution with mean $\theta$ of $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$, let $Y = \ln{X}$. Find the mean of $Y$.

We are also given the gamma function, $\Gamma(z) = \int_0^\infty t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt$

My approach is to first find the CDF of $Y$, then it's PDF, and then calculating expectation via $E[Y] = \int y \cdot f_Y(y)dy$

Would this yield the correct answer?

Is there a faster, more efficeint approach?

Have I made a mistake anywhere?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Approach so far: (Has been added at the end of comments)

How can I go from using a given result that

$$\gamma = - \int_0 ^\infty ln(x) e^{-x} dx = 0.5772..$$
When I currently have :

$$E[\ln (X) ] = \frac{1}{\theta}\int_0 ^\infty ln(x) e^{\frac{-x}{\theta}} dx$$

Comment: What is the random variable $X$?  In general the procedure you outlined is fine, but there may be simpler ways to find the mean.

Comment: $X$ is exponentially distributed with mean $\theta$ - sorry for not making it clear! I will update my post with an attempt at the solution in a bit, hopefully someone can check :)

Comment: I thought it might be the the sum of the $X_i$, or their average.

Comment: Yes, you should be right. But just in case I misinterpreted the wording of the Question, it is as follows:

The geometric mean of a sequence of positive numbers $x_1, . . . , x_n$ is $ (x_1 . . . x_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$. Let$ X_1, . . . , X_n$ be a random sample on an exponential distribution with mean $θ$. We would like to use the geometric mean 
$G = (X_1 . . . X_n)^{\frac{1}{n}} $ to estimate $θ$. All results may be expressed in terms of the gamma function...

Let $Y = \ln X$ where $X$ is exponential with mean $\theta$. Obtain the mean of $Y$.

I was confused as to why there were no commas?

Comment: OK, so $X$ is exponential mean $\theta$. The relationship with $G$ is that $\ln G=\frac{1}{n}(\ln X_1+\cdots +\ln X_n)$, and since the mean of a sum is the sum of the means, $\ln G$ has mean equal to the mean of the $\ln X_i$, which is exactly what you are being asked to compute.

Comment: The mean of $\ln X$ is the integral from $0$ to infinity of $(\ln x)\cdot \frac{1}{\theta}e^{-x/\theta}$. An unpleasant definite integral, which happens to have a closed form.

Comment: Ok, so im a little stuck.

I did this:
$ Y  = ln(X) \implies X = e^Y$
Then the CDF of $Y$, let's call this $G(y) $

is such that $P(Y\leq y) = P(\ln(x) \leq y) = P(X \leq e^y)$

then $G(y) =   \int _0 ^{\ln(y)}  \cfrac{1}{\theta} exp(-x/ \theta) dx$

...

and eventually got that 
$E[Y] = \int _{- \infty}^{\infty} -y/\theta^2 - 1/ \theta dy$ which is infinite so I must be wrong.

whre did I make a mistake

Comment: I had suggested a "faster" way of finding $E(y)$.  But your way, the cdf of $Y$  is $\int_0^{e^y}(1/\theta)\exp(-x/\theta}\,dx$. We can evaluate, easily enough, then differentiate, or differentiate under the integral sign.

Comment: Hi, sorry Andre, I fell asleep in the middle of last night!
Your way is much more simpler, and I think what they want us to do - although I am at a standstill;
We are given: $$\gamma = - \int_0 ^ \infty \ln (x) e^{-x} dx = 0.577216...$$

using your method, we have $$E[\ln X] = \int_0 ^\infty \ln(x) \cdot \frac{1}{\theta} e^{-x/\theta}$$

But I dont see how to massage this equation so that I can use the result of the $\gamma = \dots$ which they have given?
tried a change of variables :
let $x/ \theta = \tau $  then we have $\int_0 ^\infty$ $\ln (\tau \theta) 1/ \theta e^{- \tau} d(\tau \theta)$

Comment: ^ Where can I go from there? since i know have an $\ln(\tau \theta)$ instead of $\ln (\tau)$

Comment: Yes, you change variables. Recall that $\ln(\tau\theta)=\ln(\tau)+\ln(\theta)$. Now it's over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going through the pdf is feasible, but it is  easier to note that
$$E(\ln X)=\int_0^\infty \ln x\cdot\left(\frac{1}{\theta} e^{-x/\theta}\right)\,dx.$$
Let $x=u\theta$. Then $\ln(x)=\ln\theta+\ln u$ and our integral becomes
$$\int_0^\infty (\ln\theta) e^{-u}\,du +\int_0^\infty (\ln x)e^{-x}\,dx.$$
The first integral is $\ln\theta$ and the second, by the (non-elementary) fact  you were given is $-\gamma$.